# Not Directing Http/www traffic to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, https, routes

so I have installed ssl certificate on my server, so if search using https://www.domain.info its secure connection. but if i search using [www.domain.info](http://www.domain.info) or http://www.domain.info it doesnt redirect to https for a secure connection.

this is my current  htaccess content

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do share your htaccess rule file in form of text in your question along with any errors if you are getting thank you.

Comment: Thank you for informing. I have edited the question, added htaccess content and there's no error.

Comment: So on which conditions you want to add https to URL? I mean you want to apply https along with removing www to request, correct? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: so I have installed ssl certificate on my server, so if search using https://www.domain.info its secure connection. but I search using www.domain.info or http://www.domain.info it doesnt redirect to https for a secure connection.

Comment: Ok, could you please check if your htaccess file is enabled or not, try putting a garbage line like `----------` in your htaccess file and try hitting any link if you get 500 internal server error which means your htaccess file is enabled else its NOT, let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok so I tried that but its not giving any error. I can still access my site.

Comment: Then it means your htaccess file is NOT enabled which means any rewrite rules you write will not work.

Comment: so can you suggest/guide how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Akshay, did it work for you my solution? Kindly do let me know in answer's comments section.

Comment: @AkshayTrivedi: You already have correct rule to make it `https` and remove `www.` from URLs. Most likely your .htaccess is not enabled. Please search on net how to enable it

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for your response. I will work on enabling htaccess right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your htaccess file is not enabled mod rewrite rule at present, try un-commenting line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` once. Plus go through article https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-set-up-enable-htaccess-apache for understanding on how to enable htaccess file.

Also change your rules to following.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: is this solution for code igniter? I checked our code, we don't have load module line to uncomment. I have deploying and routing part in my task so I asked the programmer about it, he mentioned to ask if it is for the code igniter. Thank you

Comment: @AkshayTrivedi, your question was about htaccess rules so this answer is ony dealing with it. Could you please do let me know if you have tried and what you got after trying it.

Comment: I tired working according to your steps. there's no load module line to uncomment in the code and I changed the htaccess but its the same result.. Is there any other way to enable htaccess in code igniter,

Comment: @AkshayTrivedi, I just Googled it and found link https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-set-up-enable-htaccess-apache check this one and let me know here how it goes? Your Quick response will be appreciated :)

Comment: @AkshayTrivedi, Just using my previous comment's suggestion here: Ok, could you please check if your htaccess file is enabled or not, try putting a garbage line like `----------` in your htaccess file and try hitting any link if you get 500 internal server error which means your htaccess file is enabled else its NOT, let me know how it goes.

Comment: so I worked according to the article you provided. Everything is working properly, now the only thing needed is its not taking me from non - www to www. Sorry for the delayed response .

Comment: @AkshayTrivedi, but I thought you don't want to have `www` in your url? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Wait @RavinderSingh13 its working perfectly now. I applied the htaccess codes you provided _ added one more rule for non www and steps from the article you suggested. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AkshayTrivedi, keep learning and keep sharing on this great site, keep posting good questions and answers :)